# R: Progress bar does not start at 0

Tags: r, progress-bar

I've attempted to write a progress bar with R's "progress" library. In all efforts made, the bar starts at over ten percent.

I'm using the exact example code (https://github.com/r-lib/progress#readme), and have the current version of the package (1.2.0). I'm running this code in the Anaconda distribution of RStudio, version 1.0.153.

```
library(progress)
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = 100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  pb$tick()
  Sys.sleep(1 / 100)
}
```

The progress bar should begins at 0, but instead begins at 20%. It does complete correctly at 100%.

Comment: You have a very short time between ticks, and the console is only going to update so many times per second. If you increase the sleep time to `1 / 10` or something, do you still see the issue?

Comment: Yes. Short time between ticks shouldn't matter, as the first tick *starts* at ~12-20%, *then* Sys.sleep() is called. What could be happening such that ~12-20% is printed when pb$tick() is the very first method call in the loop? Everything else is spaced evenly after that.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Add `pb$tick(len=0); Sys.sleep(0.5); pb$tick(len=0)` right after you make the progress bar. You might need to adjust the sleep time. This is unsatisfyingly hacky but works.

---

This illustrates the problem a little better:

```
f <- function(wait = 1, total = 5) {
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(total = total)
  pb$tick(len = 0) # doesn't seem to work

  for (i in 1:total) {
    print(i)
    pb$tick(len = 1)
    Sys.sleep(wait)
  }
}
```

If I run `f(1)` I get:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[=============>----------------------]  40%[1] 3
[=====================>--------------]  60%[1] 4
[============================>-------]  80%[1] 5
```

But if I run `f(1/10)` I get:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[=====================>--------------]  60%[1] 4
[============================>-------]  80%[1] 5
```

And `f(1/100)` results in:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

So there must be some sort of startup time for the progress bar. On my computer it's about 140 ms (try `f(1/1000, 200)`). But even if I set wait to something long (like `f(5)`) I still don't get a first display.

---

If I add a pre-wait time *after* `pb$tick(len = 0)` (not before), then I get a first tick (as long as the pre-wait time is ~> 200 ms):

```
f <- function(wait = 1, total = 5, pre = 1) {
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(total = total)
  pb$tick(len = 0) # doesn't display
  Sys.sleep(pre)   # pre-waiting time
  pb$tick(len=0)   # now it displays the 0% bar
  
  for (i in 1:total) {
    print(i)
    pb$tick()
    Sys.sleep(wait)
  }
}
```

```
> f(1/100, 5, 0.3)
[======>---------------------------]   0%[1] 1
[======>---------------------------]  20%[1] 2
[=============>--------------------]  40%[1] 3
[===================>--------------]  60%[1] 4
[==========================>-------]  80%[1] 5
```